# javascript arrays and/or jquery $.inArray() and .splice()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working with an array that can have only 12 values in it; 1 through 12. These values can exist in any order. I need to go through the array and find the first unused value and then set it to a variable.

For example, if the array contains the values [1, 7, 2, 5, 10] I want to set the variable to 3 since it was the first unused number in numerical order. I am working with jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.1, but if this can be solved in plain javascript that is fine too!

Below is my code, which I know is wrong since it always sets the variable to 1. Note: tCounter is a global array used in several functions, so I do not want to modify the contents here. This is why I created tArray to splice values out of. Thanks for your help!

```
var i;
var t;
var tArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(i, tCounter)) {
        tArray.splice($.inArray(i, tArray), 1);
    }
}

if (tArray.length <= 0) {
    term = 1;
} else {
    term = tArray[0];
}
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: inArray returns an index 0-n if it is found, or -1 if it is not, you can't simply use it as true/false

Comment: You'll want to do `if (jQuery.inArray(i, tCounter) !== -1)`

Comment: why are you splicing values out of tArray, when you have the value that you are looking for stored in i? Can't you just return i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors that I can see in your current implementation.

First, your `for` loop indexing appears to be one off. In its current state, it will not check for the existence of the number 12, (due to your conditional `i<12`).

Second, your `if` statement actually evaluates to false when it should be true. If the index in the array is 0, (0 evaluates to false in Javascript), you should enter the statement. Taking what you have I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
  var i;
  var t; //this isn't used, perhaps it should be 'term'?

  for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
     // if we find a number that isn't in tCounter, we exit the loop.
     if (jQuery.inArray(i, tCounter) === -1) {
         term = i;
         break;
     }

     //sets term to null if all numbers are present in array.
     term = null;
  }
```

If your values were not the numbers 1-12 but rather arbitrary numbers, your idea of splicing values out of an array would work nicely, but as is, you really don't need the var tArray at all.

**Sidenote:** In an interesting comparison, it seems that if you are looking for the fastest implementation possible, you should use `tCounter.indexOf(i)` instead of `jQuery.inArray(i, tCounter)`, I wasn't sure which was faster, but [this](http://jsperf.com/in-array-vs-inarray-vs-indexof) nifty test confirmed my suspicions.

Comment: Yes, you were right, "t" was supposed to be "term". Thank you so much for your help, I truly appreciate it! I have always been leery of javascript arrays, so it is great to learn more about them! I will definitely switch it to indexOf() as faster is better.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution is to iterate from 1-12 and check for the existence of that value in the array. Like this:

```
var i;
for(i=1; i<12; i+=1) {
   if (tArray.indexOf(i) === -1) break;
}

term = i;
```